# pdf uploaded with FileReader

Tags: javascript, pdf

I'm currently working on an upload file function using file API it works great with png jpg and gif, but I'm also trying to upload and store pdf but when I retreive an uploaded pdf it's unreadable (I'm using pdfjs to display, 'real' pdfs are displaying fine).

I'm using FileReader readAsDataUrl as seen in serveral tutorials but my knowledge of this tool is fairly limited.

Here is my code,  :

```
uploadMenu() {
if (this.state.title && this.state.file) {
  this.setState({loading: true})
  const self = this;
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function(e) {
    const data = reader.result;
    const jsonToSend = {
      "title": self.state.title,
      "position": self.state.select,
      "imageName": self.state.file.name,
      "image": data
    }
    fetch('/new/content/' + self.state.topID, {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(jsonToSend)
    }).then((res) => res.json()).then((res) => {
      self.setState({loading: false})
      if (res.status === "ok") {
        self.props.close();
        self.props.refresh();
      } else {
        self.setState({errorMessage: res.status});
        self.setState({errors: true});
      }
    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(this.state.file);
  this.setState({errors: false});
} else {
  this.setState({errorMessage: "All fields are required"});
  this.setState({errors: true});
}
```

any insight on FileReader or on what I'm missing would be great !

Answer (score 0):

At least, missing semicolons (`:`) in these two lines:

```
this.setState({loading: true})
self.setState({loading: false})
```